# Increasing the number of explanation tags returned by concept insights conceptual search results

Tags: concept-insights

I am using conceptual search on a corpus of documents that I uploaded into Conceptual Insights. The results I get back in explanation_tags for each of the relevant documents have a very high relevance score (upwards of 0.998). However by default i get back only a small set of concepts as explanation_tags per document (it was always 6 concepts in my case).

The lowest relevance score for a concept in my explanation tag is 0.9983. Given such a high score of relevance for the least relevant concept in the explanation_tags, I feel that there might more concepts which maybe relevant to my conceptual search but are being suppressed by the API, while returning the json result.

Is there any intrinsic cutoff or limit for the set of related concepts returned in the explanation tags? Would it be possible to modify this threshold to get more concepts with slightly lower relevance scores through a query paramter?

Comment: any coding effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the number of concepts serving as explanation between the query and each of the returned documents by adding the `&explanation_tags=<int>` parameter to your `/conceptual_search` query. For example, if we take the example from the documentation:

> curl -u username:password -G -d
>   "ids=[\"/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Artificial_intelligence\"]" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/public/ibmresearcher/conceptual_search"
>   | jq .results[].explanation_tags[].concept.id | wc -l

we get 60. If we add `explanation_tags=10` as a parameter:

> curl -u username:password -G -d "explanation_tags=10" -d "ids=[\"/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Artificial_intelligence\"]" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/public/ibmresearcher/conceptual_search" | jq .results[].explanation_tags[].concept.id | wc -l

we get 100